# Помогите разобраться с MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, socketio

решил сделать на python-flask видеоконференцию через socketio, дело в том что я могу получить blob от MediaRecorder

```
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream,options);
                    mediaRecorder.start(3000);
                    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                      console.log('Got blob data:', event);
                      if (event.data.size > 0) {
                        socket.send({id: stream.id, data: event.data});
                      }}
```

Получаю byte в python, пересылаю обратно по broadcast всем подключенным и не понимаю как теперь преобразовать byte в звук и видео(картинку).... помогите решить проблему.

```
var socket = io();
        var uuid = generateUUID();
        
        // Соединение с socketio 
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('join', {'username': 'Иван', 'room': '12', 'uuid': uuid}); // Тут комната в которую входит пользователь
            
        });
        
        socket.on('message', function(message) { // здесь я получаю данные при каждом получении от клиента Blob
            (async () => {
                  let blobStream = new BlobStream();
                  let users = {};
                    let user = new Receiver(uuid);
                    var blob = new Blob([message.data], {type: "video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus"});
                    user.uuid = uuid;
                    users[user.uuid] = user;
                    blobStream.addDataCallback((blob) =>
                        socketioDataEvent({
                        uuid: user.uuid,
                        data: blob
                    })
                    );
                  function socketioDataEvent({ uuid, data }) {
                    if (!users[uuid]) throw new Error(`Unknown user ${uuid}`);
                    users[uuid].appendToSourceBuffer(data);
                  }
                })();
            })
        function Receiver(uuid) {
          let video = createVideoEl(uuid);
          let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
          video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
          let sourceBuffer = null;
          mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", function() {
            sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus");
          });
          this.appendToSourceBuffer = async (blob) => {
            if (
              mediaSource.readyState === "open" &&
              sourceBuffer &&
              sourceBuffer.updating === false
            ) {
              sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(await blob.arrayBuffer());
            }
            if (
              video.buffered.length &&
              video.buffered.end(0) - video.buffered.start(0) > 100 &&
              sourceBuffer &&
              sourceBuffer.updating === false
            ) {
              sourceBuffer.remove(0, video.buffered.end(0) - 100);
            }
          };
        }

        function BlobStream() {
          let preview = createVideoEl(uuid);
          let callbacks = [];

          getWebCam().then((stream) => {
            //preview.srcObject = stream;

            let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start(2000);
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
              if (event.data.size > 0) {
                socket.send({user: uuid, data: event.data, room: '12'});
                //callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback(event.data));
              }
            };
          });

          this.addDataCallback = (callback) => {
            if (typeof callback === "function") callbacks.push(callback);
          };
        }
        
        // Генерация guid
        function generateUUID() {
            var d = new Date().getTime();
            var d2 = (performance && performance.now && (performance.now()*1000)) || 0;
            return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                var r = Math.random() * 16;
                if(d > 0){
                    r = (d + r)%16 | 0;
                    d = Math.floor(d/16);
                } else {
                    r = (d2 + r)%16 | 0;
                    d2 = Math.floor(d2/16);
                }
                return (c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
            });
        }
        
        function createVideoEl(uuid) {
        if ($('#' + uuid).length == 0){
            let video = document.getElementById('video_grid').appendChild( document.createElement('video'));
              video.autoplay = true;
              video.width = 300;
              video.height = 300;
              video.id = uuid;
              return video;
            }
            else 
            {
            let video = document.getElementById(uuid);
            return video;
            }
          
        }

        async function getWebCam() {
          return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не уточнили как именно вы возвращаете данные, но я предположу что возвращается точно такой же `Blob` (в любом случае, байты в `Blob` вы же сможете превратить? ;) ).

Собственно, на основе вот [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354182/14168867) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122595/14168867) ответов получаем такую картину:

```
let video = createVideoEl();
// создаём MediaSource и крепим его к video
let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

// создаём SourceBuffer в который будем докидывать данные
let sourceBuffer = null;
mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", function () {
  // по умолчанию Chrome использует этот,
  // но в вопросе не было показано что лежит в options, поэтому у вас он может быть другим
  // важно заметить, что если кодек указан не тот, то ничего не заработает
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus");
});

async function appendToSourceBuffer(blob) {
  if (
    mediaSource.readyState === "open" &&
    sourceBuffer &&
    sourceBuffer.updating === false
  ) {
    // в оригинале просто передавался просто blob, но у меня не завелось
    // решение найдено было тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122595/14168867
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(await blob.arrayBuffer());
  }

  // стараемся не переполнить память
  if (
    video.buffered.length &&
    video.buffered.end(0) - video.buffered.start(0) > 100 &&
    sourceBuffer &&
    sourceBuffer.updating === false
  ) {
    sourceBuffer.remove(0, video.buffered.end(0) - 100);
  }
}

// Начинаем получать наш стрим
blobStream(appendToSourceBuffer);

async function blobStream(ondata) {
  let stream = await getWebCam();

  // для наглядности кинем его на страницу тоже
  let preview = createVideoEl();
  preview.srcObject = stream;

  let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  mediaRecorder.start(200);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0 && typeof ondata === "function") {
      ondata(event.data);
    }
  };
}

function createVideoEl() {
  let video = document.createElement("video");
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.width = 300;
  video.height = 300;
  document.body.appendChild(video);

  return video;
}

async function getWebCam() {
  return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
  });
}
```

- Пример 1 - [codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/xxVzvWG](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/xxVzvWG)
- Пример 2 - [codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/ExKeyZb](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/ExKeyZb)
- [MediaSource | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)
- [SourceBuffer | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer)

Comment: Это работает хорошо, но где вклиниться для отправки на сервер "arrayBuffer" и получения с сервера того же "arrayBuffer", что бы показать в браузере?
Задумка такая:
1. Человек заходит на сайт (разрешения камера, микрофон)
2. Отправляю на сервер данные (камера и звук)
3. Отправляю всем подключенным к socketio данные
4. Получаю данные у разных клиентов и отображаю видео и воспроизвожу звук.

Comment: т.е. я как бы получаю картинку с камеры, отправляю данные (видео и аудио) на сервер, с сервера получаю данные о других камерах и о своей... если кто-то новый присоединился, то добавляю его камеру на страницу и т.д.

Comment: @Иван, для отправки, можно вклюниться там же, где вы это сделали в своём коде, т.е. внутри `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable`. Просто я в этом месте сделал callback из-за отсутсвия бекэнда. Для добавления данных в буфер воспроизведения, вам нужно вызывать `appendToSourceBuffer` и подавать в него полученные данные. Т.е. это будет событие socket.io в котом получаете event.data, который отправил другой пользователь

Comment: Шикарно, просто супер, спасибо за помощь, очень помог ))

Comment: Сделал вроде все, но все равно не задача про отображение, это мне нужно создавать новые теги <video> и в каждом отображать blob не совсем получается.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? При подключении клиента, создаёте для него новый `MediaSource` и `<video>`, при отключении уничтожаете

Comment: т.е. я создаю все соединения MediaSource для своей камеры, потом для каждого подключенного я создаю ещё по одному MediaSource? Ладно, нужно просто по внимательней код рассмотреть... Спасибо, больше не беспокою )))

Comment: Угу, для каждого входящего потока нужен свой `MediaSource`. Но хочу заметить, что для своего потока(правое окошко) я не использую `MediaSource`, а в `<video>` напрямую вставляю `MediaStream` (две строки после "// для наглядности кинем его на страницу тоже")

Comment: Да, я уже заметил, отображаю свою камеру тоже через blob, задержка правда есть из-за 200 миллисекунд, я просто пока что не совсем понимаю что делать когда с сервера придут данные, я должен добавить новое окно отображения с другой камеры (я генерирую uuid для каждого соединения) мне получается нужно создать ещё один video к нему MediaSource а получая с сервера id - он же uuid и данные подгружать в sourceBuffer потом, каждый пакет так. id = video, data = отображению на странице. вроде в голове все правильно а вот в коде буду экспериментировать )))) спасибо за помощь ))

Comment: Стал высвечивать такую ошибку : Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null.
    at appendToSourceBuffer (http://127.0.0.1:5847/:203:19)

Comment: и blob.arrayBuffer is not a function, когда передаю с сокета данные

Comment: так ну данные с сокета я конвертнул в Blob проблема ушла, var data = new Blob([message.data], {type: "video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus"});, теперь борюсь над тем как открыть mediaSource
логика пока что такая: приходят данные id и data, где id это уникальный код и data - данные, проверяю есть ли такой id на странице, нет, то создаю mediaSource, создаю тэг с id возвращаю его, слушателя addEventListener("sourceopen") и передаю в appendToSourceBuffer (mediaSource, элемент video и data), но пишет appendToSourceBuffer что mediaSource = closed... не пойму как открыть его.

Comment: Добавил пример с подключением нескольких клиентов. Если всё же ещё будут вопросы, то думаю лучше перейти в чат, как это предлагает sof

Comment: Добавил код ниже... пока что что-то не то... (((

Comment: Спасибо, все сделал, все получилось, единственное сейчас борюсь с тем что бы не плодить подключенных на сервере, нужно как то определять отключение пользователя что бы их убирать со страницы, а так все норм, спасибо.